# Jenkins restart does not work jsvc.exec not found

Tags: java, jenkins, jsvc

In our current jenkins installation (using a war file running inside jetty on ubuntu) whenever we try to do a safeRestart or a restart it hangs displaying a page "Please wait while Jenkins is restarting"

This never finishes and we have to restart jetty manually.

This is what we see in the logs:

```
WARNING: Failed to restart Jenkins
java.io.IOException: Failed to exec 'jsvc.exec' No such file or directory
    at hudson.lifecycle.UnixLifecycle.restart(UnixLifecycle.java:84)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$23.run(Jenkins.java:3418)
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue.  Please let me know if you figured anything out

Comment: same issue here aswell

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps at [this link](https://community.bitnami.com/t/failed-to-restart-jenkins-failed-to-exec-jsvc-exec/35730/2) (we use Bitnami Jenkins) to increase Xms to 512 and Xmx to 1024 and restarted Jenkins. This seems to have fixed the issue for me. I haven't seen the Exception in the logs for some time now.

So it seem that it was probably just a JVM memory allocation issue. Try increasing Xms and Xmx JVM args for your Jenkins instance and see if that helps.